# String matching algorithm with more weight given to more unique words?

Tags: python, matching, string-matching, word-frequency, record-linkage

I've been looking into Python and using the record.linkage toolkit for address matching. I've found the string matching algorithms such as levenshtein are returning false matches for very common addresses. Ideally an address with one very unique word matching would be more highly scored than very common words, e.g. "12 Pellican street" and "12 Pellican road" is a better match than "20 Main Street" and "34 Main Street".

Is there a method for incorporating a weighted string matching, so that addresses with more unique words carrying more importance for matching?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found using the qgram distance over the levenshtein distance take into consideration the frequency of the string in the dataset.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`fuzzywuzzy`](https://pypi.org/project/fuzzywuzzy/)

Installation

```
pip install fuzzywuzzy
```

Usage:

```
In [1]: from fuzzywuzzy import fuzz

In [2]: fuzz.ratio('12 Pellican street', '12 Pellican road')
Out[2]: 76

In [3]: fuzz.ratio("20 Main Street","34 Main Street")
Out[3]: 86
```

So, for address matching, we can create a custom function like this. It will match separately for street number and street name and find the average of that.

```
def match_address(address_1, address_2):
    st_no_1, rest_1 = address_1.split(maxsplit=1)
    st_no_2, rest_2 = address_2.split(maxsplit=1)
    return (fuzz.ratio(st_no_1, st_no_2) + fuzz.ratio(rest_1, rest_2))/2
```

Execution:

```
In [4]: match_address('12 Pellican street', '12 Pellican road')
Out[4]: 85.5

In [5]: match_address("20 Main Street","34 Main Street")
Out[5]: 50.0
```

Comment: Good answer, but how come `Ideally an address with one very unique word matching would be more highly scored than very common words, e.g. "12 Pellican street" and "12 Pellican road" is a better match than "20 Main Street" and "34 Main Street" ` is not the case in your answer ?

Comment: Yes this doesn't answer my question, fuzz.ratio would use levenshtein distance and not consider the uniqueness of the word match, only the similarity of the characters in the string. As you have shown, "20 Main Street" and "34 Main Street" is considered the better match.

Comment: @McLovin Yeah, thanks for the point. "Max", I updated the code which matches your requirements.